# Jomsocial get current profile data

Tags: php, api, object

I'm trying to develop a custom module in PHP for jomsocial.

How can I retrieve information about the current profile being visualized by user? (Not info about looged user itself but about the profile displayed!) It would be enough getting username and id, but does anyone know a way to get info and how much info? I've being searching in Jomsocial API with no luck ;(

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Return user with the given id
$user =& CFactory::getUser($userId);

// Return current logged-in user. If no one is logged-in, it will
// return a visitor object
$user =& CFactory::getUser();
```

Retrieve any user-specific information from custom field

```
$user =& CFactory::getUser($userId);
$data = $user->getInfo('FIELD_CODE');
```

It's quite simple.
If you want to see the entire contents, just do a var_dump($user) or a print_r($user);

For instance, if you want to get the gender of a user, you can use

```
$gender = $user->getInfo('FIELD_GENDER');
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this answer is very late but here goes for those who have the same problem.

I recently finished some tasks related with Jomsocial Version: 2.8.3 in Joomla 2.5.11 and I faced the problem you described.

In the module you can add the following lines of code

```
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_community' . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'core.php');
$userinfo = & CFactory::getActiveProfile();
```

So, the $userinfo object has all the information you want, the id of the current displayed profile will be:

```
$userinfo->_userid
```

Hope this help to other devs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

NONE OF THE ABOVE ARE CORRECT, I HAD THE SAME ISSUE. 
To get the user info for the currently viewed profile you MUST use:

```
$this->_user = CFactory::getRequestUser();
```

This is the ONLY way to get the info of the currently viewed profile and not return logged in user profile info...

Answer (score 0):

$cuser = CFactory::getUser();
$userid = $cuser->id;
echo $data
This will give the id of current user, n like this we can get the username n other details of current user.
Like
$username = $cuser->username;

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to retrieve the currently logged in user is shown bellow. If no one is logged in, it will return "guest" object.

$cuser = CFactory::getUser();

1. $cuser->id;
2. $cuser->name;
3. $cuser->username;
4. $cuser->email;
5. $cuser->password;
6. $cuser->block;
7. $cuser->registerDate;
8. $cuser->lastvisitDate;
9. $cuser->getThumbAvatar();

OR

You can refer [this](http://documentation.jomsocial.com/wiki/JomSocial_User_Object) complete official documentation for JomSocial userObject on their website.